# fmt and command line commands (with e.g. mylatexformat)

Tags: format-files

I want to speed up the compilation process, so I splitted the main document in two files:

### MWE

> preamble.tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\csname endofdump\endcsname
```

> main.tex

```
\begin{document}

\ifdefined\test
    :)
\else
    :/
\fi

\end{document}
```

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

pdftex -ini -jobname="preamble" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "preamble.tex"
pdflatex -fmt preamble "main.tex"
```

### Problem

However, I want to pass data from command line to tex to get a happy smilie,

```
#!/bin/bash
pdftex -ini -jobname="preamble" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "preamble.tex"
pdflatex -fmt preamble "\def\test{1}\input{main}"
```

and I stumble across an interactive mode where I don't know what to do.
Using the *-no-parse-first-line* doesn't help either.

> texput.log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=preamble 2014.12.16)  16 DEC 2014 14:17
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\def\test{1}\input{main}

==============================================================================
JOB NAME         : "texput"
CUSTOMISED FORMAT: "preamble"
PRELOADED FILES:
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)

==============================================================================
*
! Emergency stop.
<*> \def\test{1}\input{main}

End of file on the terminal!


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3 strings out of 494701
 113 string characters out of 6174765
 48268 words of memory out of 5000000
 3561 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 7639 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 8i,0n,22p,42b,30s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem in the end? I get into this situation when combining preamble pre-compilation with tikz externalization...

Comment: @ingomueller.net: Unfortunately I haven't found a solution :/ An idea for a workaround: generating a config.tex file by the scripts which are used to build the document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no expert on this, but I guess `mylatexformat` doesn't scan through input files recursively, thus never encounters the literal `\begin{document}` in `main.tex`, necessary to mark the end of the format according to its [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mylatexformat/mylatexformat.pdf). At least for your MWE, it works if you issue `\endofdump` (the alternative to mark the end of the format, to avoid two `\begin{document}`) on the command line:

```
pdflatex -fmt preamble "\endofdump\def\test{1}\input{main}"
```